# SQL Server Clustering - Active/Active or Active/Passive?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering

What is the logic of the Active/Active cluster vs Active/Passive cluster?

I have searched a lot and read lots of documents but have not found the answer.

In active active cluster can I have 1 database which is in shared storage and that database have 2 instances?

What is the pros/cons of active active cluster?

In active passive cluster can I have one database which is in shared storage and it use active node. If active node is shutdown, will the passive node become the active node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Active/Active refers, typically, to the idea of having multiple copies of a database available concurrently.  However, in SQL Server, there is no way to accomplish that *for read-write* databases, other than the somewhat edge case of sharding data across mutliple instances.  In SQL Server, Active/Active is normally used to denote a multi-node Windows Server Failover Cluster that has multiple SQL Server *instances* installed, where each node has a separate instance.  However, for this to work successfully, each node needs to be configured with enough memory and CPU resources to successfully serve *all* instances in case that node is the only node left running at some point.

Active/Passive refers to having a multi-node cluster where one node serves the database(s), while the other node is available to take the load if the primary node fails.

As an example of Active/Active, consider the following:

2 computers configured in a Windows Server Failover Cluster, Node "A" and Node "B".  The cluster has two instances installed, "X" and "Y".  Typically, "X" runs on node "A", and "Y" runs on node "B".  This means the horsepower of both machines can be combined to serve the needs of both instances.  If, however, node "A" goes down, then node "B" will host *both* "X" and "Y" instances.

MSSQLTips.com has a great [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1554/sql-server-clustering-active-vs-passive/) comparing the two types of clustering.

MSDN has a good [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/momalek/2012/04/10/creating-an-activeactive-sql-cluster-using-hyper-v-part2-the-clustered-instances/) on how to create an Active/Active cluster using Hyper-V.

From the description in your question it sounds to me like you want a typical 2-node cluster with a single instance serving a single database.  The database resides on shared storage so that if the active node (the one *currently* serving the database) goes down, the passive node will automatically start up the instance and begin serving the database from there.  Once the original node is brought back online, the instance could be moved back over to it, although that is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Does SQL server FCI (always on) natively support active active mode?

Comment: Exactly the way I describe in my answer.   And [FCI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/windows-server-failover-clustering-wsfc-with-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is not the same thing as [Always On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: And if, by Active-Active Mode, you mean two SQL Server instances serving the same database that are both read-write and updates to one instance are immediately visible in the other instance with ACID compliance, then no.

Comment: 1) My understanding was that Always on technology umbrella consists of 2 things - FCI and AG. AO-FCI is where during installation you add the instance to an existing cluster. Where as AO-AG is technology to have copy of one or more dbs on 2 separate SQL server instances (successor of mirroring). Please correct me here. 2) I have read your answer again, and I understand that active active (separate databases) is possible using Windows Server Failover Cluster (is this also called FCI?).